# Problem in animating polygon

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, logic

Hi I am trying to move my black colored polygon downward. But As soon as I run my application my polygon gets invisible! I think My logic of move function is wrong. Can anyone help me out in figuring this out as i am a newbie in opengl and c++.
This is What I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "RGBA2.h"
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;
int screenWidth=640;    
int screenHeight=480;

float posx = 0.0f;
float posy = 0.0f;
static float prevtime= 0.0f;
float currtime;



void myDisplay(void)
{
glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0,11,0,11);

glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,11);

//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f(1,1,0);
glTexCoord2f(-1,-1);    
glVertex2f(1.0,2.0);
glTexCoord2f(1,-1);
glVertex2f(1.0,10.0);
glTexCoord2f(-1,2); 
glVertex2f(10.0,10.0);
glTexCoord2f(1,2);
glVertex2f(10.0,2.0);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f(0,0,0);
glVertex2f(posx+2.0,posy+6.0);
glVertex2f(posx+2.0,posy+8.0);
glVertex2f(posx+2.5,posy+8.0);
glVertex2f(posx+2.5,posy+6.0);

glEnd();

glFlush();
```

}

```
void move(int t)
{
long ltime;
ltime = time(NULL);
srand(ltime);
//currtime=gettime();

//static float movebearing=0.0f;
float dx=2.0;
float dy= 8.0;
 posy -= dy;
if (posy >= 11-9)
{   
    posy= 0.0f;
dy= 0.0;
}


glutTimerFunc(1000,move,1);
glutPostRedisplay();
}

float gettime()
{
static __int64 i64Frequency=0;
static __int64 i64BeginCount=0;
if (i64Frequency==0)
{ 
    QueryPerformanceFrequency ((LARGE_INTEGER*)&i64Frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter ((LARGE_INTEGER*)&i64BeginCount);
}
__int64 i64CurrentCount;
QueryPerformanceCounter ((LARGE_INTEGER*)&i64CurrentCount);
return (float)(i64CurrentCount-i64BeginCount)/i64Frequency;
}

void delay(int ms)
{
prevtime =glutGet (GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
currtime=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

int diff= currtime -prevtime;
while(diff < ms)
{
    currtime=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    diff=currtime - prevtime;
}
}








RGBApixmap pix[6];



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);

glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);
glutInitWindowPosition(20,20);

glutCreateWindow("TEXTURING");



glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay); 
glutTimerFunc(1000,move,1);


pix[0].readBMPFile("brick.bmp",1);
pix[0].setTexture(11);


glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after first call to Move function, posy is decreased by 8.0 => posy = -8.

When you draw your rectangle, you put some coordinates, which also become negative and ywhole polygon is out of window.

BTW: And I totally don't understand your Move function:

- why do you have time functions there?
- why is there this weird "if (posy >= 11-9)" - when posy becomes 3 or higher, you set it to 0? So if you add dy instead of subtracting, it will be still on one place?